# Bookmarklet for Ffffound.com does not work in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, bookmarklet

I recently got an account at [Ffffound.com](http://www.ffffound.com) which is essentially an image collecting/bookmarking site. In order to 'collect' images you use [Ffffound's bookmarklet](http://ffffound.com/bookmarklet#bookmarklet) which finds images on a site, puts blue borders around them, and makes them clickable and thus able to be saved to your account.

I have been struggling all day with the bookmarklet and cannot get it to work in Firefox (version 44.0.2 on Mac OSX 10.10.5).

Here is the bookmarklet's code:

```js
javascript: void((function() {
  var % 20e = document.createElement('script');
  e.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
  e.setAttribute('charset', 'UTF-8');
  e.setAttribute('src', 'http://ffffound.com/bookmarklet.js');
  document.body.appendChild(e)
})());
```

I've tried editing the bookmarklet's code in ways suggested in similar threads to no avail. I don't know enough about programming at this point in time to be able to spot anything really obviously wrong with the code, and maybe it's not the code, maybe there's a conflict with an addon or a setting or some such.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: It doesn't work in Safari either now.

Comment: Can you post on which websites you have tried this bookmarklet?

Comment: Not sure if it is your typo or it is wrong in your actual URL:  `var % 20e = ` is supposed to be `var%20e =`, or simply `var e =` (FF will encode the space for you when you are updating your bookmark)

Comment: Hi, I've tried adding from many, many sites-- other photo aggregating sites like Tumblr, miscellaneous artists' websites (www.emohr.com, http://www.dinovalls.com/), sites that other users have added from (http://www.tm-research-archive.ch/designers/heinrich-fleischhacker/ for example), Google image results, and so on. Once in a blue moon the bookmarklet will add an image successfully and then cease to work again entirely.

Comment: I have changed the code to simply "var e" and unfortunately that didn't seem to change anything.